# Storing partial results into NSMutableDictionary efficiently

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

target_results is a NSMutableDictionary. Is this an efficient way to store partial sums into a list? Can you suggest any improvement?

```
NSInteger temp_key = [rs intForColumn:@"some_int_field"];
NSInteger existing_value = [[target_results objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp_key]] intValue];

if (existing_value > 0)
{
    //add to existing
    [target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10+existing_value] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp_key]];
}
else
{
     //new entry
[target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10] forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp_key]];
}
```

Comment: You should be using `integerValue` when you retrieve from `target_results`, since you are putting the result into an `NSInteger`.

Comment: Good point. Any suggestions about performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most correct way to optimise is to profile and find where the actual bottlenecks are, if any. That said, working from first principles...

Firstly, there's no need to call `NSNumber` twice (three times in the code, twice at runtime). Each call creates a new object, so there's a memory allocation overhead to that. So that's a cut to:

```
NSInteger temp_key_int = [rs intForColumn:@"some_int_field"];
NSNumber *temp_key = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp_key_int];

NSInteger existing_value = [[target_results objectForKey:temp_key] intValue];

if (existing_value > 0)
{
    //add to existing
    [target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10+existing_value] forKey:temp_key];
}
else
{
     //new entry
[target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10] forKey:temp_key];
}
```

The if statement also doesn't seem to achieve anything. So you could further reduce the code to:

```
NSInteger temp_key_int = [rs intForColumn:@"some_int_field"];
NSNumber *temp_key = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:temp_key_int];

// will create a new entry or replace an existing entry, as per the normal behaviour
// of NSMutableDictionary
NSInteger existing_value = [[target_results objectForKey:temp_key] intValue];
[target_results setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:10+existing_value] forKey:temp_key];
```

I seriously doubt you'll see any performance issues with that or with the original code. However, you describe your data structure as a list, so you might consider using an `NSMutableArray` rather than a dictionary, assuming you can place an initialisation step.

Comment: Thank you Tommy! I'm not using NSMutableArray for 2 main reasons: 1.This list can grow very much and dictionaries have better performance for finding items  2.In the end of this processing I'll need to sort the dictionary by value.